# What does this hyperref warning mean?

Tags: hyperref, warnings

I would like to know what is this means?

```
usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package hyperref Warning: Option `letterpaper' is no longer used.
```

This is my works:

```
\hypersetup{
    plainpages=false,       % needed if Roman numbers in frontpages
    pdfpagelabels=true,     % adds page number as label in Acrobat's page count
    bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat's bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat's toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat's menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
%    pdftitle={uOttawa\ LaTeX\ Thesis\ Template},    % title: CHANGE THIS TEXT!
%    pdfauthor={Author},    % author: CHANGE THIS TEXT! and uncomment this line
%    pdfsubject={Subject},  % subject: CHANGE THIS TEXT! and uncomment this line
%    pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % list of keywords, and uncomment this line if desired
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=true,        % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue,         % color of internal links
    citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=cyan           % color of external links

\ifthenelse{\boolean{PrintVersion}}{   % for improved print quality, change some hyperref options
\hypersetup{    % override some previously defined hyperref options
%    colorlinks,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    urlcolor=black}
}{} % end of ifthenelse (no else)

\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,oneside,final]{book}
```

Comment: Please show the instruction that gives riseto this warning message.

Comment: sure. Many thanks.   package     usr/local/texlive/2019/texmfdist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty  hyperref Warning: Option `letterpaper' is no longer used.

Comment: citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    urlcolor=black}
}{} % end of ifthenelse (no else).
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,oneside,final]{book}

Comment: It's just a warning message. You specify the option `letterpaper` in the `\documentclass` instruction, and documentclass-level options get passed automatically to all packages that are loaded in the preamble -- including the `hyperref` package. All warning message is telling you that `hyperref` doesn't do anything anymore with the `letterpaper` option. You can safely ignore the warning.

Comment: Many thanks for your replay Mico.

Comment: @Mico no, a documentclass option wouldn't give this warning, you only get it if you use it in the call to hyperref itself. There must be a `\usepackage[letterpaper]{hyperref}` somewhere.

Comment: @Sara - Does your document contain an instruction such as `\usepackage[letterpaper]{hyperref}`? Please advise.

Comment: Is \documentclass really after \hypersetup?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Yes, I do.

Comment: @Mico, Yes, I do.

Comment: \ifthenelse{\boolean{PrintVersion}}{
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=0.75in,right=1.25in]{geometry}   % For twoside document
}{
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=0.75in,right=1.25in]{geometry}   % For oneside document
}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext} % Lots of math symbols and environments
\usepackage{graphicx} % For including graphics 

\usepackage{nomentbl} 
\makenomenclature

Comment: \usepackage{ifpdf}

\newcommand{\href}[1]{#1} % does nothing, but defines the command so the
    % print-optimized version will ignore \href tags (redefined by hyperref pkg).
%\newcommand{\texorpdfstring}[2]{#1} % does nothing, but defines the command
% Anything defined here may be redefined by packages added below...

Comment: % Hyperlinks make it very easy to navigate an electronic document.
% In addition, this is where you should specify the thesis title
% and author as they appear in the properties of the PDF document.
% Use the "hyperref" package

Comment: % N.B. HYPERREF MUST BE THE LAST PACKAGE LOADED; ADD ADDITIONALPKGS ABOVE
\usepackage[\ifpdf pdftex,\fi letterpaper=true,pagebackref=false]{hyperref} % with basic options
  % N.B. pagebackref=true provides links back from the References to the body text. This can cause trouble for printing.

\hypersetup{
    plainpages=false,       % needed if Roman numbers in frontpages
    pdfpagelabels=true,

Comment: This is from beginning

Comment: @Sara - So there you have it: You need to delete `letterpaper=true` from `\usepackage[\ifpdf pdftex,\fi letterpaper=true,pagebackref=false]{hyperref}`.